# How to pass in a filename from a SQLite database in Android?

Tags: android, database, sqlite, expandablelistview

I am having trouble figuring out a solution to my problem. I have an ExpandableListView that creates a new MediaPlayer instance when the child view is clicked. Currently, this is done with a hard coded link to the file in my raw folder, but I want to switch it to take the file name from the database, and then use that filename to load the corresponding audio file from the raw folder.

My database is set up something like this:

```
_id|English|Hanzi|Pinyin|Filename

1  |Hello! |你好  |nǐ hǎo|hello
```

The cursor is already loaded and fills the ExpandableListView. How do I go about loading this instance of mediaPlayer with the filename in the database, so that every child will load it's own audio file?

```
    //load cursor
    public void fillData() {
    Cursor mGroupsCursor = mydb.fetchColorsGroup();
    startManagingCursor(mGroupsCursor);
    mGroupsCursor.moveToFirst();

    //Basic ExpandableListView Adapter
    MyExpandableListAdapter mAdapter = new MyExpandableListAdapter(mGroupsCursor, this,
            R.layout.group_item,                    // Group layout
            R.layout.child_item,                    // Child layout
            new String[]{"English"},                // Group fields
            new int[]{R.id.english_text},           // Widget ids for group data
            new String[]{"Hanzi", "Pinyin"},        // Child fields
            new int[]{R.id.foreign_text, R.id.romanization});          // Widget ids for child data
    final ExpandableListView elv = (ExpandableListView) this.findViewById(R.id.shell_expList);
    elv.setAdapter(mAdapter);                         // Set the list adapter



    // Set the listener for child clicks
    elv.setOnChildClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                                    int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {


                    // Stop the media player
                    if (mediaPlayer != null) {
                        mediaPlayer.release();
                    }


                    // Start the media player
                    mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.shi);
                    mediaPlayer.start();
                    return true;
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use one MediaPlayer instance! Don't recreate one for each row. You can use its reset() and methods for passing new data source. To pass this new data source in your adapter's getView/bindView (for the row) you can use setTag() method on the view. To avoid creating ambiguity, add an id in res/ids.xml (you can also add it in res/styles.xml if you don't want to create another resource file) such as  and then do something like:

`public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
   ...
   // some method retrieving the song path from the cursor such as
   String uriLiteral = cursor.getString(COLUMN_INDEX_SONG_URI);
   // then you can do
   view.setTag(R.id.view_tag_song_play_path, uriLiteral);
   return mView;
 }`

And in the click listener:

`@Override
public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
  String uriLiteral = (String) v.getTag(R.id.view_tag_song_uri);
  if (uriLiteral != null) {
    mediaPlayer.stop();
    mediaPlayer.reset();
    mediaPlayer.setDataPath(uriLiteral);
    mediaPlayer.prepare(); // .start();
  }
}`

*Code is as is: mediaPlayer may have something other than setDataPath depending on what type of handle you are using to reference your music files (eg, disk path, assets ID, etc).